# PHP variable won't print

Tags: php, html

I have an html file with a form (with method=get) with inputs that takes a username with name `user`, and password `pwd`.
The submit button then directs to a file called `admin.php` which looks like this:

admin.php:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
    echo "user: $user";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I can see the variables in the url being passed over, but when I load my admin.php it only prints `user:` and nothing else. I know this is probably a stupid question, but why is this so?

Comment: care to explain why the downvote? I was only following a guide here (which made no mention of having to do anything like $_GET['var']):
http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/ddws/17.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try printing it like so:

```
echo "user: " . $_GET['user'];
```

Comment: Sure thing! Had to ;) Assume it was just a quick typo.

Answer (score 5):

This will make it work.

```
$user = $_GET['user'];
```

Comment: Cool, I was following this tutorial http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/ddws/17.html and they made no mention of having to do this

Comment: PHP can be configured to do this automatically, but it isnt considered a safe practice.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "user: " . $_POST['user'];
```